# How to inject github secrets in application.properties file of Spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, environment-variables

How can I inject a GitHub secret in the ***application.properties*** file of a Spring-Boot application before the execution of build and deploy?

This is my current YAML file:

```
name: Heroku deployment

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Deploy to Heroku
      uses: AkhileshNS/heroku-deploy@v3.12.12
      with:
        heroku_api_key: ${{secrets.HEROKU_API_KEY}}
        heroku_email: ${{secrets.HEROKU_EMAIL}}
        heroku_app_name: event-handler
```

This is my application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
```

I currently inject some environmental variables to handle Heroku deployment, I would like to update my YAML file so as to inject also the values of database properties from GitHub secrets. Is it possible to do it using a similar approach? The attempt to align the YAML file as if it was an application.properties did not work, it seems not quite right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare **application.properties** file for string replacement:

```
spring.datasource.url=<db_url>
spring.datasource.username=<db_username>
spring.datasource.password=<db_password>
```

And modify yaml file with additional commands:

> ```
> name: Heroku deployment
>
> on:
>   push:
>     branches: [ master ]
>
> jobs:
>   build:
>
>     runs-on: ubuntu-latest
>
>     steps:
>     - uses: actions/checkout@v3
>
>     - name: Update db url
>       run: sed -i 's/<db_url>/${{ secrets.DB_URL }}/' src/main/resources/application.properties
>
>     - name: Update db username
>       run: sed -i 's/<db_username>/${{ secrets.DB_USERNAME }}/' src/main/resources/application.properties
>
>     - name: Update db password
>       run: sed -i 's/<db_password>/${{ secrets.DB_PASSWORD }}/' src/main/resources/application.properties
>
>     - name: Deploy to Heroku
>       uses: AkhileshNS/heroku-deploy@v3.12.12
>       with:
>         heroku_api_key: ${{secrets.HEROKU_API_KEY}}
>         heroku_email: ${{secrets.HEROKU_EMAIL}}
>         heroku_app_name: event-handler
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the response. It's similar to what I ended up doing.